# Java streams peek() equivalent in Mutiny Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, java-17, mutiny, quarkus-reactive

Sometimes I want to peek what's the value that is flowing through the steam.

I cannot attach a debugger from my IDE. Because I will see unresolved objects instead of values. If I try to `.await().indefinetely()` it will raise an exception.

So I'm looking for something like in java streams I can simply use `peek(e -> System.out.println(e))` which will simply print the value.

I have something like below

```
public Uni<TenantDraft> getTenantById(@PathParam("tenantKey") String tenantKey) {
    return tenantService.findByTenantKey(tenantKey)
            .onItem().ifNotNull().transform(TenantMapper.INSTANCE::tenantToTenantDraft)
            .onItem().ifNull().failWith(ForbiddenException::new);
}
```

Comment: It's **peek** not **peAk**.  Please check the [first googled link: Peeking at the streams](https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-invoke-and-call/) . Briefly, there are synchronous `invoke` and asynchronous `call` methods to peek at the various events.

Comment: A cursory read of what [Mutiny is all about](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/1.7.0/) suggests that you're not looking at streams, you're looking at events, and acting on them.   Because they are events, you have no (real) control over when they arrive or when you'll observe them. In this case, you may want to decompose this down a lot further to see the event flow between stages, since the API doesn't seem to allow for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use:

- `.log()` which will log all the event
- `.invoke(item -> System.out.println(item))`